# An estimator for a histogram/summation based calculation

Tags: estimation, histogram, curve-fitting

I'm looking for some ideas on how I can estimate the results of a particular calculation on a data set. The data is a very simple mapping of X=>Y where X is a real value and Y is a positive integer. The calculation that needs to be performed is given value Q what is the sum of all Y having X < Q.

What I want is a way to come up with an estimator of the sum for any given value Q. I'm looking for ideas, or pointers, to such an estimator.

Some key points, applicable to the software in which it will be used:

1. The estimator must need a relatively small amount of data, preferably alterable such that is the number of estimator variables increase the quality increases
2. There are sensitive areas in the domain, for example the accuracy from A..B is more important than B+. In general the accuracy requirement goes down as we go further right in the domain.
3. Perhaps the most vital requirement, it must be possible to modify the estimator's data directly from the addition/removal of a data item in the original set (that is, I cannot calculate over the entire data set each time to get the estimator values -- though occasionally is okay) *(Update: If you have an idea but it doesn't meet this point, or aren't sure, please tell me anyway, I'm sure I could adapt many approaches to be valid for this point)*

My first approach is to treat this as a histogram and simply divide the data into buckets of fixed sizes. For those sensitive areas I simply have more divisions. Unfortunately I'm finding that this is requiring too much data for the estimator to be accurate on the lowest part of the domain.

To improve the histogram approach I've been looking for curve approximations within the histogram buckets. Something like variance seems appealing since it can be done with Point 3.

*This is kind of mix of topics together, from programming to statistics to algorithm design. I'm asking for ideas and direction here since I think the problem is most related to the data set / statistical aspect.*

---

Update for first comment:

1. A..B / B+ in Point 2 just represent an arbitrary part of the domain. For example between 0 and 5 accuracy is more important than in 5+. These values will be constants.
2. The data set is in constant flux via additions/removals. The data set at Time 0 may have an empty intersection with the data set at Time X. It is therefore important that modifying the estimator through a series of additions/removals results in the same values as if it were completely recalculated. Note when I say cannot be recalculated it would be okay if there is some way to do partial recalculation (think constant time in terms of algorithm complexity).

Also to the add/subtract, in the areas of high accuracy it is assumed the addition/removal of a single element will be highly significant. Note that I'm also okay if you have an idea that doesn't qualify for this aspect, since I'm sure I can find someway to adapt it.

Comment: some questions for clarification: 1. What is A..B / B+ in 2. ? We do know your data. 2. I wonder about 3.: If you have too much data to recalculate everything for every change, then does the change of single values even matter (regarding the acceptable error of the estimator) ?